# Counterexamples to the Artin-Rees Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, topological-rings

This well known Lemma about $I$-stable filtrations asserts:

**Lemma** (Artin-Rees) *Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $E$ a finitely generated $A$-module.
Let $F$ be a submodule of $E$ and $\{E_i\}$ an $I$-stable filtration. Then the induced filtration on $F$ is $I$-stable.*

One of its immediate corollaries is the following:

**Corollary**  *Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ an ideal.
Then the following equality holds:*
$$I \left(  \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} I^i\right)=\left(  \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} I^i\right)$$

I'm looking for a counterexample to the Artin-Rees Lemma in one of the two forms above, when the ring A is not Noetherian.

Does anyone have some ideas or references?

Thank you!

Comment: The corollary is a particular case of Krull Intersection Theorem and you can find counter-examples for non-noetherian rings on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71699/counter-examples-to-krulls-intersection-theorem).

Comment: The matter is that the only demonstration of Krull Intersection Theorem i know uses this Lemma...

Comment: The MO link contains a counterexample to the corollary (and hence of the Lemma!).

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring everything together and answer this question, here's how you can adapt one of the counterexamples shown in the [Math Overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71987/425619).
We start with the Noetherian ring, not finitely generated module case first, and then show how to transform that into the non-Noetherian ring, finitely generated module case.

> For $R$ noetherian and $M$ not finitely generated you can take the following example from Kaplansky, *Infinite Abelian Groups*: The abelian group $G$ with generators $x$ and $y_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots$ and relations $px=0$, $x=py_1=p^2y_2=\dots=p^ky_k=\dots$ ($p$ some fixed prime) satisfies $G_\omega=\bigcap p^kG=\langle x\rangle$, but $pG_\omega=0\ne G_\omega$.

(Change of notation with respect to the question: $R$ is the ring, $M$ is the module, $N \subseteq M$ is the submodule.)

Take $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = G$ and $N = G_\omega =\langle{x}\rangle$ with the example above. ($G$ can be seen as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module because $G$ is an abelian group.)
Note that $R$ is Noetherian but $M$ is not finitely generated as an $R$-module.
Let $I = p\mathbb{Z} \triangleleft R$ for the fixed prime $p$.

Take the $I$-adic filtration on $M$, which is $(M_n)_{n \ge 0} := (p^nG)_{n \ge 0}$.
This is automatically $I$-stable.
However, the induced subpsace filtration on $N$ is $(M_n \cap N)_{n \ge 0} = (N)_{n \ge 0}$ since by construction $N \subseteq M_n$ for all $n \ge 0$.
This is clearly not $I$-stable as $IN = p\langle{x}\rangle = 0 \ne N$.

Now to get the example with $R$ **not Noetherian**, again as suggested by the above answer on MO,

> Building upon this example, you also get an example for the case $R$ non-noetherian and $M$ finitely generated: with the same $G$, you can set $R=\mathbb Z\times G$ with $G$ as a square-zero ideal, $M=R$ and $I=pR$. Now, $\bigcap I^n=0\times G_\omega$ again satisfies $I\bigcap I^n\ne\bigcap I^n$.

we can take $R = \mathbb{Z} \times G$, $M = R$, and $N = 0 \times G_\omega = 0 \times \langle{x}\rangle$.
You can see that $R$ is not Noetherian because the ideal $0 \times G$ is not finitely generated.
Now apply reasoning very similar to the above to get the same result.

---

You can also show that $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = G, N = G_\omega$ gives you a counterexample to the exactness of $I$-adic completion when the hypotheses of Artin-Rees are not satisfied.
Indeed, we have the following exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$$
If $\widehat{\phantom{A}}$ denotes completion with respect to the $I$-adic topology, then $\widehat{N} \cong N$ because with the $I$-adic topology, $IN = 0$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$, so this is the discrete topology, and similarly $\widehat{M/N} \cong M/N$.
But the sequence
$$ 0 \to \widehat{N} \to \widehat{M} \to \widehat{M/N} \to 0$$
is not exact, that is,
$$ 0 \to {N} \to \widehat{M} \to {M/N} \to 0$$
is not exact because the map $N \to \widehat{M}$ is not injective.
Indeed, under this map, $x \in N$ maps to the coherent sequence $(x, x, x, \ldots)$ in $\widehat{M}$ which is equal to $(0, 0, \ldots)$ because $x = py_1 
= p^2y_2 = \cdots$ and so $x \in p^nG = I^nM$ for all $n \ge 0$.